# N-Functions (Nice Young functions)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis

A mapping $\Phi:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ is termed an N-function (nice Young function) if

(i)  $\Phi$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$;

(ii) $\Phi$ is convex on $[0,\infty)$;

(iii) $\lim\limits_{t \rightarrow 0}\frac{\Phi(t)}{t}=0$;

(iv)$\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\Phi(t)}{t}=\infty$.

In the book "Robert A. Adams, John J. F. Fournier, Sobolev Spaces" the authors claim that this definition is equivalent to $\Phi$ has an integral representation such that 
$$
\Phi(t)=\int_0^t\varphi(s)ds,\quad t\in [0,\infty),
$$
where $\varphi$ be a real valued function defined on $[0,\infty)$ and having the following properties

(i*) $\varphi(0)=0$, $\varphi(t)>0$ if $t>0$, $\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow\infty}\varphi(t)=\infty$;

(ii*) $\varphi$ is nondecreasing;

(iii*) $\varphi$ is right continuous.

My first question is : We know that a convex function on an open inerval is continuous. Using this fact and conditions (ii) and (iii) can we write  condition (i) as $\lim\limits_{t \rightarrow 0^+}\Phi(t)=\Phi(0)=0$?

My second question is : The function $\Phi(t)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
0& , & t\leq 1 \\
t\log t&,& t>1
\end{array}
\right.$ is an N-function or not? It seems like it satisfies the all conditions (i)-(iv). But according to second definition $\varphi(t)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
0& , & t< 1 \\
\log t+1&,& t\geq1
\end{array}
\right.$ and it doesn't satisfy the condition (i*). Where is the mistake?

Comment: For short: yes to both.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thanks for your answer. It seems like the function $\Phi$ satisfies the all conditions. But according to book "Alois Kufner, Luboš Pick, Oldřich John, Svatopluk Fučík, Function Spaces" it is not an N-function.

Comment: I cannot understand why. (i),(iii) and (iv) are pretty trivial, and for any $t>1$ we have $\Phi''(t)=\frac{1}{t}>0$, hence (ii) is fulfilled, too.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I make some edition on question. Can you look again, please?

Comment: Maybe in (ii) we have to take "convex" as "strictly convex", hence $\Phi(t)$ fails to be strictly convex on $[0,1]$.

Comment: FYI, the term "N-function" is a poor choice of words since it will likely to be mistaken with functions having [the property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luzin_N_property) that the image of a measure zero set is a measure zero set. In fact, that's what I thought this question was about when I clicked on it.

Answer (score 0):

The second condition in (i*) implies that $\Phi$ must be strictetly nondecreasing that is if $x <y$ then $\Phi(x)<\Phi(y)$. You must add this condition on $\Phi$ in the first definition. You will note that your example does not satisfy this condition. Therefore it is not a young function (in this sens).

Comment: How do you know that conditions (i) - (iv) do not imply that $\Phi$ is strictly nondecreasing?